# Fixing AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MakeRasterLayer_management'

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, attributeerror

I'm trying to change my slope map's labels and colors to the specific ones I want which are shown in the code, but when I run this script it produces an AttributeError that doesn't make sense to me since I imported arcpy into my script.

Code:

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder"
    inRaster = "USGS_13_n37w082_20220512.tif"

    outSlope = Slope(inRaster, "PERCENT_RISE")
    outSlope.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\slope2.tif")

    myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 3.99, 1], [4, 9.99, 2], [10, 15.99, 3], [16, 30.99, 4], [31, 60.99, 5], [61, 999999, 6]])
    outReclassRR = Reclassify(outSlope, "VALUE", myRemapRange,"NODATA" )
    outReclassRR.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\reclass2.tif")
    arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer_management("outReclassRR", "outReclassRR_layer")
    arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(outReclassRR, reclass_copy.lyr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in main
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MakeRasterLayer_management'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arcpy` tools can either be used from their module or are aliased so they can be used from the top level.

From the `management` module:

```
arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer
```

Or by the top-level alias:

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management
```

Comment: Thanks! The first way worked for me! Apparently the "_management" section was what was causing the issue.

Comment: @Darell no, `arcpy.*management*.MakeRasterLayer_*management*` is what won't work.  `arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management` will work as well as `arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer`

Comment: Ohh my bad, I read that wrong. Yes, that's true. arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer is what worked for me.